# Is there a way to use python to create an excel file that has formatting features such as underlines, bold text, different colours etc.?

Tags: python, excel, vba, formatting

I want to create an Excel file using Python and have it formatted in a particular way.

Do you have to use VBA once the Excel file is created to create a macro that does the formatting? Or is there some sort of module that I can use to do it entirely in Python?

Comment: @SujithKumar you spell `grammar` like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python library that can do that is `xlsxwriter`.

You can find the documentation here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io